# Can I use my typedef structure with pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

Here I wrote some code with a pointer to a structure. I put in some `typedef` but I don't know how to use it with my pointer structure. I can't find any help on the internet. Always typedef structure, or pointer structure, but not with these 3 involved.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct student{
    char NAME[20];
    int ID;
    float GRADE;
    char INSTRUCTOR[20];
}student;


int main()
{
    struct student Raf = {"Rafael Sunga", 1775, 1.35, "Kenneth Auxillos"};
    struct student *ptr_Raf; //declaring ptr to a structure
    ptr_Raf = &Raf; //asigning address of variable with & 
    
    printf("Student Name: %s\n", ptr_Raf->NAME);
    printf("ID: %d\n", ptr_Raf->ID);
    printf("Grade: %.2f\n", ptr_Raf->GRADE);
    printf("Instructor: %s\n", ptr_Raf->INSTRUCTOR);

}
```

Comment: Please describe what makes you doubt.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Does this code not work for you?

Comment: 1 pointer typedef. 2 structure pointer. What is the third?

Comment: If I get you right, you want to define a type, that already is a pointer. That is possible via `typedef struct {} student, *pstudent;` But you should never ever do this. Hiding pointers in typedef is considered bad practice.

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750178/15168) – TL;DR, the answer is "No", with possible exceptions for function pointers.

Comment: thanks for the replies guys, I'll check into it, I kept searching where the f is the reply box and couldn't find it earlier lmao

Comment: The code shown doesn't use the typedef name `student`; it only uses the structure tag `struct student`.  You could replace either or both occurrences of `struct student` with just `student` inside `main()` and the meaning of the code would not change.  Note that it is unusual to use all-capitals in the member names; all-capital notation is normally reserved for macros and enumeration constants.  Use lower-case or mixed-case names for structure member names.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct student //old data type
{
    char NAME[20];
    int ID;
    float GRADE;
    char INSTRUCTOR[20];
}student; //new data type


int main()
{
    student Raf = {"Rafael Sunga", 1775, 1.35, "Kenneth Auxillos"};
    student *ptr_Raf; //declaring ptr to a structure
    ptr_Raf = &Raf; //asigning address of variable with & 
    
    printf("Student Name: %s\n", ptr_Raf->NAME);
    printf("ID: %d\n", ptr_Raf->ID);
    printf("Grade: %.2f\n", ptr_Raf->GRADE);
    printf("Instructor: %s\n", ptr_Raf->INSTRUCTOR);

}
```

I found the solution, I just removed the "struct" and left the student in, works fine, thannks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The so-called name space rules of C are a bit confusing. When it comes to structs there are 3 different ones that apply: struct tag, struct member and ordinary identifiers.

- `struct student` is a struct tag.
- `typedef ... }student;` is an ordinary identifier (like any variable name).

Since these exist in different name spaces, we can use the same identifier. When you type `struct student` in your code, you refer to the struct by tag, if you just type `student` then the ordinary identifier. As you can tell it gets very confusing when they are given the same name, so we shouldn't do that.

How to declare structs is otherwise a style issue with no obvious right or wrong. The Linux world uses the `struct name { ... };` style with struct tags. The rest of the world uses the `typedef struct { ... } name;` style.